# Python scraping attribute vale from xhtml:link

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I am trying to gather the value from within the href attribute. I have done this before but can't seem to get it to work for "xhtml:link".

I have tried the bellow:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse('items.xml').getroot()

for type_tag in root.findall('xhtml:link'):
    value = type_tag.get('href')
    print(value)
```

and the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<url>
    <loc>https://www.example.com</loc>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com"></xhtml:link>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/"></xhtml:link>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/"></xhtml:link>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/"></xhtml:link>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/"></xhtml:link>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/"></xhtml:link>
</url>
```

I have tried to find a reason behind this but can't seem to find anything. Any advice would be amazing thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`xhtml` is a namespace and it needs option `namespaces=` in `findall()`

First: I had to add `xmlns:xhtml="your namespace"` to run it - probably you also have it.

I had to use the same namespace in `findall()`

```
text = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<url xmlns:xhtml="your namespace">
    <loc>https://www.example.com</loc>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com"></xhtml:link>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/"></xhtml:link>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/"></xhtml:link>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/"></xhtml:link>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/"></xhtml:link>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/"></xhtml:link>
</url>'''

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(text)#.getroot()

for type_tag in root.findall('xhtml:link', namespaces={'xhtml':'your namespace'}):
    value = type_tag.get('href')
    print(value)
```

I don't know if there is function to ignore namespaces.